# Background color for row breaking outside of the container class in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a pretty basic setup as I'm trying to figure out why this is happening. I have a container div and inside that container there are 3 rows. I'm trying to attached a background color to one of those row, and it does work but when I size down to mobile, I see the container class, which has a white background color, and my row background color taking up the entire width of the viewport instead of just taking up the space inside the container clip.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Learn</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contentContainer">
            <section class="row row-steps">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 track selectedTract">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0">
                                 <h3><span>Step 1:</span> Choose a Track</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-pull-10 col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-0">
                                <img src="img/badge-dashed-empty.png" alt="dotted circle">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 track">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0">
                                 <h3><span>Step 2:</span> Choose a Course</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-pull-10 col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-0">
                                <img src="img/badge-dashed-empty.png" alt="dotted circle">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 track">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0">
                                 <h3><span>Step 3:</span> Choose a Lesson</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-pull-10 col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-0">
                                <img src="img/badge-dashed-empty.png" alt="dotted circle">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #f4f5f7;
}

.contentContainer{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.contentContainer.row-steps{
    background-color: #eaf2f5 !important;
}

.contentContainer img{
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.contentContainer h3{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.contentContainer h3 span{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.selectedTract{
    background-color: #63c4aa;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

what what my results look like:
[image]

I would like the color to stay within the bounds of the container div

Answer (score 1):

Apply `overflow:hidden` to container:

```
.contentContainer{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why this isn't the default behavior? I would think for that to happen you would want to use container-fluid?

Comment: That's because of `.contentContainer img` has margin of 5px.